# HERE Maps: RouteOptions setTime side effects

Tags: android, here-api

In some cases when I calculate a route in my app it is for a trip that will occur in the future. My thinking is that when I call setTime (on RouteOptions) with the time they will leave and the DEPARTURE option it will use this info to inform the TTA. Is that the case or should I just avoid setting this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly as you describe. If you provide a departure time in the route options, the result will take time based restrictions into account. This in turn will impact both returned route (e.g., if a road is closed at night, a different route might be returned) and time it takes to travel that route (e.g., if trains travel less frequently at certain times, the same route might take longer).